# Get Bounded Script ID from another project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

Is there a way to get the id of a script embedded in a spreadsheet (not the id of the spreadsheet) from another script (in other file)?

I have a main standalone script that copies a spreadsheet that contains a script (web app code). I need to get the id of this script and use it to create a deployment with the apps script API REST.

Is there any other way to programmatically deploy a bounded web app script in a spreadsheet?

Apologies for my bad English, I´m using the translator

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve `Is there any other way to programmatically deploy a bounded web app script in a spreadsheet?`, at first, it is required to retrieve the script ID of the container-bound script.

But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the script ID of the container-bound script cannot still be retrieved from outside of the project using only Google Apps Script. And also, the the script ID of the container-bound script cannot be retrieved from the file ID of the parent Google Docs file. This has already been reported to the Google issue tracker as the Feature Request. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037)

When the script ID of the container-bound script can be retrieved, you can use "REST Resource: projects.deployments" in Apps Script API.

#### Note:

- If the script for retrieving the script ID is in the same project, the script ID can be retrieved using `ScriptApp.getScriptId()`.
- The file ID of Google Docs can be retrieved from the script ID of the container-bound script using the method of "Method: projects.get" in Apps Script API. But in the current stage, the contrary cannot be done.

#### References:

- [getScriptId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getScriptId())
- [Method: projects.get](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/get)
- [REST Resource: projects.deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments)